# Models.py for recommendation system

Tags: django, database, django-models

My webapp displays a list of movies taken from JSON file in bootstrap card format.Each individual card exists for each movie. I need to take user ratings(1-5) for n movies from the user, default value being 0 if the user doesn't rate it.

I want to save it in a row-column format in my database where each row represents a user and columns depicts the movies and the table represents ratings by each user for each movie.

my views.py looks like this :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import json
from .models import *
from . import forms
def list(request):
        movies_data=open('movies.json').read()
        movies = json.loads(movies_data)
        return render(request, 'home.html', {'movies' : movies})
```

my home.html looks like this:

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
    <center> <h1 class="display-3">Welcome to Movie Finder!</h1>
    <p class="lead"> Your one-stop and best recommender of movies.</p></center>


            <div class ="container">
            <div class="row">
            {% for movie in movies %}
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3">
            <div class="card h-8">
            <div class="card-group">

                <div class="card text-center" style="width:20rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{movie.img_url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{movie.title}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Rating : {{movie.users_rating}}</h5>
                <h5 class="card-title">Year : {{movie.year}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text"><h5>Description:</h5> {{movie.description|truncatewords:10}} </p>
                <br></br
                <a href="{{movie.imdb_url}}" class="btn btn-dark">Explore</a>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

what should be my models.py and the procedure of taking input? I have googled a lot but not being able to reach an end. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Im not completely understanding your question, but for models to support your requeriments:
*Notice that Im using `Client` and not `User` because, User is a django default model which you can also use and its quite helpfull to handle logins and sessions* [Check it here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/)

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Movie(models.Model):
    movie_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    ...

class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    rate = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Having the models you need to add the form into your `home.html`.. that means

- Adding a new path to your `url.py`
- Creating a function to receive and save the data in your `views.py`
- Add the form inputs in your `home.html`

Im posting a simple code, but you have to arrange it to handle exceptions and finishing at your desire.

**url.py**

```
(...),
# must have the <int:user> to receive the pk of the user
path('^home/<int:user>/rating/$', views.rating, namespace='rating'),
```

**views.py**

```
def rating(request, user):
    base_context = {'request': request}
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        # access to the POST data, as you want N movies, you could name them movieX with X been a number, you should do a loop here to iterate. Im making a one case only
        movie = int(request.POST['movie1'])
        rating = request.POST['rating1']
        # Check if rating exists
        try:
            r = Rating.objects.get(user.pk=user, movie.pk=movie)
        except:
            r = Rating()
        r.rating = int(rating)
        r.save()
    return redirect('appname:home')
```

**home.html**

This is you straight forward a simple form [look here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/)

Comment: what changes should be reflected in my home.html and views ?

Comment: what is the main idea. To receive from the `home.html` the rating of the user, or to use the `JSON` file to fill your database

Comment: the json file is used to display all the movies. Now when the movies are displayed, every movie has a rating field, where user can enter any number from 1-5 and the user does this for n movies out of all movies. Fields that are left empty have default value 0. So after user enters his ratings, there will be a submit button to send a post request and the ratings for all the movies for a particular user will be stored as a row. and the column heads will represent movie title. This is the main idea.

Comment: posted some help